# CSS Gradients Inside Gradients

Tags: css, colors, gradient, linear-gradients

Is it possible to use a gradient as one of the colors inside a gradient?

For my specific purpose I have an initial gradient from left to right:

```
linear-gradient(to right, red, darkgray);
```

but I'd like the darkgray part to actually be a gradient from top to bottom:

```
linear-gradient(to bottom, darkgray, white);
```

I tried the code I would expect to work:

```
linear-gradient(to right, red, linear-gradient(to bottom, darkgray, white));
```

But this doesn't seem to work, and I haven't seen anyone write about the possibility of gradients within gradients.

**EDIT: it's not possible [CSS gradients are images and cannot be used as the colors within other gradients], but @hungerstar has a good workaround below: layer a gradient with transparencies over another gradient.**

Comment: for sure not ... but you can consider multiple gradient. As a side note a gradient isn't a color, it's an image, so there is no logic to use it there

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't know what you mean. Do you mean add additional colors on the same initial left to right axis? Well if it's not possible I guess I'm out of luck. Thanks

Comment: i mean you can have multiple gradient https://jsfiddle.net/4t2kx22b/1/ and you may achieve what you need if you find how to use them

Comment: @TemaniAfif I see what you mean. Unfortunately I don't think the desired effect is possible that way and image editing software will be necessary. Thanks for the reply

Comment: well, but if you share the result you get with an image editor we may find some workaround ;) as everything can be possible with gradient

Comment: @TemaniAfif hungerstar has a good workaround in the answers below!

Comment: friend, normally to perform this type of action, particularly speaking I use `pseudo-element` for example: *div { linear-gradient(...) }* and *div::before { linear-gradient(...) }* and I compensate them in height or width (depending of course what position I want the gradient to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

[The syntax for a gradient is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient):

```
linear-gradient( 
  [ <angle> | to <side-or-corner> ,]? <color-stop> [, <color-stop>]+ )
  \---------------------------------/ \----------------------------/
    Definition of the gradient line        List of color stops  

where <side-or-corner> = [left | right] || [top | bottom]
  and <color-stop>     = <color> [ <percentage> | <length> ]?
```

And linear-gradient doesn't create a color, it creates an image.

Comment: ;( thanks for clearing that up for me. I suppose this would need to be done in image editing software. (apparently i need to wait 5 minutes before accepting your answer, will do so when I can)

Answer (score 7):

Gradients inside of a gradient is not possible.

With that said, give this a look. Since the gradients are layered on you would have to set some transparency to your colors with `rgba()` to allow the gradient from behind to show through the gradient from above.

Maybe something like this?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background:
    linear-gradient( to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba( 169, 169, 169, 0.5 ) ),
    linear-gradient( to bottom, darkgray, white );
}
```

Comment: Oh true. I can't believe I didn't think of that...
Wish I could give both you and @Axnyff the answer point, but it seems he's technically right that the answer is no. However, thanks so much for this workaround!

Comment: @JMcFar as i said, we can combine multiple gradient and do some magic ;)

Comment: @hungerstar I did, but they don't let votes from users with reputations below a certain point effect the number. I'm chopped liver

Comment: @JMcFar ah yes, you only have **3** rep, :(