# linear-gradient on different angle

Tags: html, css, gradient, linear-gradients

I want to archive a background linear-gradient (to right, from light pink to red) and fade out vertically (to bottom, to white color or opacity to 0), but it seems it's not possible to do it by using css linear-gradient.

```css
background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(224, 130, 131, 0.8), rgba(207, 0, 15, 0.8));
```

any ideas how to archive this kind of effect without using static image?

Comment: what do mean with fade out to bottom?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Gradients Inside Gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660659/css-gradients-inside-gradients)

Comment: fade out to white color or opacity to 0

Comment: @tacoshy it doesn't have to be a gradients inside of a gradient

Answer (score 1):

You need mask:

```css
.box {
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid;
}

.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  inset:0;
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#000,#0000);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(224, 130, 131, 0.8), rgba(207, 0, 15, 0.8));
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: very close to what I needed, can I set the fade out effect start from the half of the height (50px), I have tried `-webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#000 50px,#0000);`, but the result is a bit unnatural.

Comment: @RaxPat not sure what you mean by "unntural"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cv9kr7p0/, it looks like there is a blur red line on the middle

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve a background gradient from light pink to red and then fade out on bottom.

This might help you.

```css
.divX {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(224, 130, 131, 0.8), rgba(207, 0, 15, 0.8));
    /* Ignore these below */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 150px;
    }

.divX::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, rgb(255 255 255));
}
.divXcontent {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3; 
}
```

```html
<div class="divX">
    <div class="divXcontent">
        <h1>test test</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then add another div inside .divX and set position:relative and z-index to 3, for the content to be on top of everything.